# Проверить, является ли один массив подмножеством второго

Tags: массивы, javascript

Дописать функцию `contains(where, what)`. Если все элементы массива what содержатся в массиве where, функция должна возвращать true. Пустой массив является подмножеством любого массива. Порядок вхождения элементов в массив не имеет значения. Примеры:

```
contains([1,2,3], [3,2]); // true
```

Почитал, говорят, нужно использовать метод indexOf.

Не совсем понимаю, как его организовать.
Допустим, вот:

```
var where=([1,2,3,4,5,]);
var what=[2,4,1];
function contains(where, what) {
    for(var i=0;i<where.length;i++)
    if(where.indexOf(what,0));
console.log("true")
}
```

Как мне для начала вывести сообщение, что они есть в том массиве, и как организовать проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function contains(where, what){
    for(var i=0; i<what.length; i++){
        if(where.indexOf(what[i]) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```